# no sound with an USB Microphone and pulseaudio

Tags: usb, microphone, gentoo, alsa, pulse-audio

I connected my USB Microphone to my Computer, but i cant get it to work.

Pulseaudio recognizes the device, and i can see and edit it with `pavucontrol` in the Input Devices section. I also can select the microphone in various programs i tested (for example Teamspeak) and there are no errors whatsoever. There is simply no sound coming through.

I can even mute the microphone in `pavucontrol` and a little control LED on the Device switches to red, indicating that the device is muted.

Its like the Mic is muted somewhere else, but i've checked everywhere and that is not the case.
I'm using Gentoo, and all relevant modules are loaded.

Comment: I had a similar problem on my laptop with the internal microphone, whether its the same or not I don't know. Try this: go to pavucontrol where the mic is-unlink the left/right sliders and put the left one to the top and the right one at the middle bottom (lower). This worked on my laptop.